# Multiple functions event listner

Tags: jquery, addeventlistener

how can I use  one button to take data from an array of objects and populate a div with an image and text, then remove it on the next click and add another users data?

```
      $("#declineBtn").on ('click',   function(){  
                for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                  var nextUsers=data[i];
                   console.log(nextUsers.displayname);
                    function removeProfile(){$("#declineBtn").empty};

                };
```

});
 });

Comment: You might like to add some more details; this is a bit vague.   Also, you've tagged with [tag:sql] - are you expecting some form of back-end data retrieval?

Comment: add your sample codes so that we can help. At least we need to see what you have tried.

Comment: sorry for the sloppy post, Im new to all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, but not necessary, you can set attributes to keep track of the state.

```
$('#id').click(function() {
    var clicked = $(this).attr("clicked");
    if (clicked) {
        // Do whatever
        $(this).attr("clicked", "false");
    } else {
        // Do something else
        $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
    }
});
```